# How can I calculated the total sum of a repeat binding in polymer?

Tags: polymer

Example:

```
    <div id="order">
        <template repeat="{{items as item}}">
            <p>
                <span>{{item.id}}</span>
                <span class="price">{{item.price}}</span>
                <span class="qty">{{item.qty}}</span>
            </p>
            {{cpuTotal(item.qty*item.price)}}
        </template>
        <p>Total {{total}}</p>
    </div>
    <script>
        Polymer('my-form', {
            total:0,
            cpuTotal:function(x){
                this.total=this.total+x
                console.log(this.total)                
            }
        })
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Is there a way you could do it using a computed binding so I can do `{{total=total+(item.price*item.qty)}}` ?

EDIT:
The problem I now have is that `this.total` is the total of each separate item? So for each generated item in the template I have a separate total instead of the sum of them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would stick that logic into a function (say, `computedTotal()`) and then instead of this:

```
<p>Total: {{total}}</p>
```

I would have this:

```
<p>Total: {{computedTotal()}}</p>
```

Your `computedTotal()` could look like something like this:

```
computedTotal: function() {
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
       total += (this.items[i].price * this.items[i].qty);
    }
    return total;
}
```

I would avoid putting too much login in the template itself.